# Javascript does not seem to work in chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm having a tough time enabling javascript in chrome on my own webpage. Other websites seem to be able to do it pretty easily. Here's my prtty simple code but the start() function just wouldn't work.

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "javascript">
        function start() {
            alert("Hi");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "start()">
    Hi
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the `script` at the end of the `body`

Comment: The type is `text/javascript`

Comment: Doctype should be defined in different way than `<doctype html>`.

Comment: Thanks devnull69! That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is your type attribute. If you were to keep it, then it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, you don't need it (See here: http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html). You can just use

```
<script></script>
```

That will fix your function.

Although not directly hindering your function, your doctype is missing the '!' and should probably be updated

```
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 10):

You're using wrong [**`type`** Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes), it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

or simply

```
<script> </script>  //by default is type is "text/javascript"
```

Also change `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @VisioN You're right usually I don't use.  Here I used it because it had nice tabular description.  However it's now fixed by macek.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
        function start() {
            alert("Hi");           
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "start()">
    Hi
</body>
</html>
```